# Sort Column in Table - Google Chart Tools

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

The following is a table for the Google Charts API. I'm trying to sort the "Numbers" Column descending. Anyone know how to do this?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['table']});
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function drawVisualization() {
      // Create and populate the data table.
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('string', 'Names');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Numbers');
      data.addRows(3);
      data.setCell(0, 0, 'Name 1');
      data.setCell(1, 0, 'Name 2');
      data.setCell(2, 0, 'Name 3');
      data.setCell(0, 1, 1);
      data.setCell(1, 1, 2);
      data.setCell(2, 1, 3);



      visualization = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table'));
      visualization.draw(data, null);
    }


    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
    </script>

    <div id="table"></div>
```

Comment: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/table Search for event `sort` Look here for the playground https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#sort_event

Answer (score 5):

Yes. just add the following line below your data def., it will sort descending on number, and then ascendsing on name.

```
data.sort([{column: 1, desc:true}, {column: 0}]);
```

oh, you could also use this:

```
data.addRow(['Name 1',1]);
data.addRow(['Name 2',2]);
data.addRow(['Name 3',3]);
```

regards, Halma